# Creating a colum that indicates the max value

Tags: r

I have the following dataset about cars

```
   speed dist
1      4    2
2      4   10
3      7    4
4      7   22
5      8   16
6      9   10
7     10   18
8     10   26
9     10   34
10    11   17
```

I want to create a new colum that shows the maximum value of the two columns per row.

Expected output:

```
   speed dist maxvalue
1      4    2    4
2      4   10    10
3      7    4    7
4      7   22    22
5      8   16    16
6      9   10    10
7     10   18    18
8     10   26    26
9     10   34    34
10    11   17    17
```

Comment: `df1[cbind(1:nrow(df1), max.col(df1))]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R, you could use `pmax` and `do.call` as below:

```
df$mx <- do.call(pmax,df)
df
   speed dist mx
1      4    2  4
2      4   10 10
3      7    4  7
4      7   22 22
5      8   16 16
6      9   10 10
7     10   18 18
8     10   26 26
9     10   34 34
10    11   17 17
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
df$maxvalue <- apply(df,1,max)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use rowwise() within tidyverse to get this done, then the max function is applied to each row.

```
library(tidyverse)

speed <- c(4, 4, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11)
dist <- c(2, 10, 4, 22, 15, 10, 18, 26, 34, 17)

have <- as_tibble(cbind(speed,dist))

want <- have %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(maxvalue = max(speed, dist))
```